# Mysql counting records per day with the date next to the count

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to get the count of records per day which i can do, but i also want the date to be show, for example,

Result

```
   Date    |    Count
26/01/2015        20
25/01/2015 |      413
```

Here is an example of my data.

[image]

Comment: This is mysql. I see no dates here :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this would work.  Replace 'yourTable' with your table name

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) FROM yourTable GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to work, if i wanted to order the dates how would i do that?

Comment: Should just have to add at the end of your query `ORDER BY Date ASC` or `ORDER BY Date DESC`, assuming the dates are stored in your table as dates and not varchars.

Answer (score 0):

Get the total count and group them by date.

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`;
```